# sending multiple messages from server to multiple clients

Tags: java, sockets

In my Server class, I have to send several message of **different data types** at once to all my connected clients.

```
 public class Server() { 

     private List<ClientT> client = new ArrayList<ClientT>();         
     private String strValue = "someText";                 
     private int intValue = 20;
     private int intValueTwo = 20;

     try {
            for(int i = 0; i < client.size(); i++) {
                client.get(i).output.writeObject(strValue);
                client.get(i).output.writeObject(intValue);
                client.get(i).output.writeObject(intValueTwo);
            }           
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    class ClientT extends Thread {
        private ObjectOutputStream output;
        /* ...
           ...
           ... */   
}
```

In my Client class, I I used lineNumbers to detect which message is being send from the server.

```
  ObjectInputStream input;
  int lineNo = 0;
  String message = " ";
  try {     
        input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        while(true) {
            lineNo++;
            message = (Object) input.readObject();

            if(lineNo == 1) {
                //read first message from the server
            }
            else if(lineNo == 2) {
                //read second message from the server
            }
            else if(lineNo == 3) {
                //read third message from the server
            }   

    } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + exception);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Instead of using line numbers to identify the messages send from the server class, what is a better alternative?

Comment: I'd like to offer you a helpful comment, but your question "what is a better alternative?" is simply way too broad

Comment: because I felt that I am hardcoding it. what if I have more than 3 information being pass from the server to the client? let's say I have 10 information pass from the server. I won't want to write if(lineNo ==4) and (line==5) all the way till 10.

Comment: Since you are using an ObjectInputStream, you could put the values you need into one (serializable) object and simply send that. Java would take care of the order for you.

Comment: FYI: If you're using Java 7 you should be using try-with-resources. `try (input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {}`. This ensures the stream is cleaned up properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like any TCP/UDP packet, concatenate bytes and send them to the client which should be aware of the protocol, hence how many bytes to read and when, OR if you rather variable length messages, utilize a delimiter which still needs to be parsed by the client.

If you use a ByteBuffer, this might help you:

```
public static String getStringFromByteBuffer(ByteBuffer bb) { 
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(); 
    int bytes;
    while(true) {
        try { 
            bytes = bb.get(); 
                // format the product of two bytes and a bitwise AND with 0xFF 
            message.append("\\x"+String.format("%02x", bytes&0xff)); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
    return message.toString(); 
}
```

And here some SAMPLE code to handle the incoming byte streams with the socket's  (client's) inputstream:

```
    byte[] lengthArray = new byte [someSize]; 
    this.in.readFully(lengthArray, 0, 4); 
    this.busy = true; 
    ByteBuffer lengthBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(lengthArray);
    byte[] tcpArray = new byte[length]; 
    // read message from the remote parent peer of this instance
    this.in.readFully(tcpArray, 0, length); 
    // load message into ByteBuffer container for convenience 
    ByteBuffer tcpInput = ByteBuffer.wrap(tcpArray);
```

Good luck!